# Conversion cloud module not found

Tags: python, pip, groupdocs

Hello Stack Overflow friends!

I'm trying to use this conversion cloud module (https://github.com/groupdocs-conversion-cloud/groupdocs-conversion-cloud-python), but it's returning the module error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'groupdocs_conversion_cloud'**

I've installed the packaged through the terminal with no problem, even though the error keeps returning.

Here's my code:

```
import groupdocs_conversion_cloud

# Get your app_sid and app_key at https://dashboard.groupdocs.cloud (free registration is required).
app_sid = "3e9***ca"
app_key = "f0***ad407e1"

# Create instance of the API
convert_api = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertApi.from_keys(app_sid, app_key)
file_api = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.FileApi.from_keys(app_sid, app_key)

try:

        #upload soruce file to storage
        filename = 'FT_Manteiga virgem de cacau.pdf'
        remote_name = 'FT_Manteiga virgem de cacau.pdf'
        output_name= 'FT_Manteiga virgem de cacau.docx'
        strformat='docx'

        request_upload = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.UploadFileRequest(remote_name,filename)
        response_upload = file_api.upload_file(request_upload)
        #Convert PDF to Word document
        settings = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertSettings()
        settings.file_path =remote_name
        settings.format = strformat
        settings.output_path = output_name

        loadOptions = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.PdfLoadOptions()
        loadOptions.hide_pdf_annotations = True
        loadOptions.remove_embedded_files = False
        loadOptions.flatten_all_fields = True

        settings.load_options = loadOptions

        convertOptions = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.DocxConvertOptions()
        convertOptions.from_page = 1
        convertOptions.pages_count = 1

        settings.convert_options = convertOptions

        request = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertDocumentRequest(settings)
        response = convert_api.convert_document(request)

        print("Document converted successfully: " + str(response))
except groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling get_supported_conversion_types: {0}".format(e.message))
```

I've installed this lib using **pip install groupdocs_conversion_cloud**

Comment: check with pip list/pip freeze if it is installed okay. The name has hyphens not underscores.

Comment: @DevangSanghani no, the name has underscores, [check the example code](https://github.com/groupdocs-conversion-cloud/groupdocs-conversion-cloud-python#getting-started)

Comment: Yes underscores are there, I re-verified.

Comment: The sample code is working fine at my end. You may double check that you have set your environment variable for Python correctly.